# How to create all possible sentence of length 100 characters from a list of strings in Python

Tags: python, string, list, permutation

I am trying to create a sentence of length 100 characters from a given list of strings. The length has to be exactly one hundred characters. We also have to find all possible sentences using permutation. There has to be a space between each word, and duplicate words are not allowed. The list is given below:

```
['saintliness', 'wearyingly', 'shampoo', 'headstone', 'dripdry', 'elapse', 'redaction', 'allegiance', 'expressionless', 'awesomeness', 'hearkened', 'aloneness', 'beheld', 'courtship', 'swoops', 'memphis', 'attentional', 'pintsized', 'rustics', 'hermeneutics', 'dismissive', 'delimiting', 'proposes', 'between', 'postilion', 'repress', 'racecourse', 'matures', 'directions', 'bloodline', 'despairing', 'syrian', 'guttering', 'unsung', 'suspends', 'coachmen', 'usurpation', 'convenience', 'portal', 'deferentially', 'tarmacadam', 'underlay', 'lifetime', 'nudeness', 'influences', 'unicyclists', 'endangers', 'unbridled', 'kennedy', 'indian', 'reminiscent', 'ravish', 'republics', 'nucleic', 'acacia', 'redoubled', 'minnows', 'bucklers', 'decays', 'garnered', 'aussies', 'harshen', 'monogram', 'consignments', 'continuum', 'pinion', 'inception', 'immoderate', 'reiterated', 'hipster', 'stridently', 'relinquished', 'microphones', 'righthanders', 'ethereally', 'glutted', 'dandies', 'entangle', 'selfdestructive', 'selfrighteous', 'rudiments', 'spotlessly', 'comradeinarms', 'shoves', 'presidential', 'amusingly', 'schoolboys', 'phlogiston', 'teachable', 'letting', 'remittances', 'armchairs', 'besieged', 'monophthongs', 'mountainside', 'aweless', 'redialling', 'licked', 'shamming', 'eigenstate']
```

Approach:

My first approach is to use backtracking and permutations to generate all sentences. But I think the complexity will be too high since my list is so big.

Is there any other method I can use here or some inbuilt functions/packages I can use here? What will be best way in python to do this? Any pointers will be helpful here.

Comment: Can you reuse a word, or are duplicated words in the sentence not allowed? Also, note that you're likely to get this question closed because you're asking a broad question.

Comment: No duplicate words are not allowed

Comment: Does order matter? Does every order of a sentence indicate a new solution?

Comment: Order does matter, we have to take permutation for sure

Comment: You could probably consider it two separate problems though: the first, to find every combination of words that has length 100, and the second (more trivial) part, to take each permutation of each combination.

Comment: This is totally possible, I think. Working on it now. Exciting problem!

Comment: Are you sure the assignment is not to find just one random sentence or so? You can verify with elementary mathematics that enumerating all possible sentences is not possible.

Comment: Yes, at the end we have to find a single sentence which matches with a dynamically given sentence, but you don't know the sentence and it can anything.

Comment: If that's your core issue, how about `all((word in word_list) for word in dynamic_sentence.split()[:-1])` + a bit more code to account for the truncated bit + a bit more code to figure out if there are any duplicates?  As roeland mentions, it's not feasible to generate (let alone store) all the permutations.

Comment: The for-if antipattern. You have to change your approach then. Apply that constraint already when generating the sentence. Match the words in the given sentence one by one. Then the complexity goes down from **O(cⁿ)** to **O(n)**.

Answer (score 3):

**You can't do it.**

Think about it: even for selecting 4 words you already have 100 × 99 × 98 × 97 possibilities, almost 100 million.

Given the length of your words at least 8 of them will fit in the sentence. There is 100 × 99 × 98 … × 93 possibilities. That's approximately 7×10^15, a totally infeasible number.

Comment: When the range of possibilities is too large, the wise man looks for reasonable constraints.

Comment: @NathanielFord True, but the question doesn't give any constraints. And even if those constraints limit you to only, say, 20 words at every step, you still get a very large number of combinations.

Comment: While I originally supported NathanielFord's boldness in looking for a solution, I think you're right @roeland. Rakash, have you though about the physical storage required for the solution? By roeland's calculations, if each solution was 10 bytes, your solution set would take 7x10^10 gigabytes to store. If you don't mind me asking, what do you plan to do with that?

Comment: We are never storing anything here but generating all possible sentences to match with the one I have.

Comment: Agree that generating all possible permutations is impossible practically.  Looking at it another way, if we assume that it takes 1 second to generate a million sentences, the total work takes 7x10^9 seconds, which is give or take 200 years.

Comment: Storage isn't the issue, but the size of the solution domain. After sleeping on it I agree that it's very, very large. The only way you can reasonably constrain it is if the hundred character size is a precise requirement, rather than a ballpark requirement like you suggest. And even then ruling out possible solutions early is still quite tricky.

Answer (score 3):

This problem is similar to the problem of [partitioning in number theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29).

The complexity of the problem can (presumably) be reduced using some of the constraints that are encoded in the problem statement:

1. The lengths of the words in the words list.
2. Repeats of word lengths: for example a word of length 8 is repeated X times.

Here's a possible general approach (would take some refining):

- Find all partitions for the number 100 using only the lengths of the words in the words list. (You would start with word lengths and their repeats, and not by brute forcing all possible partitions.)
- Filter out partitions that have repeat length values exceeding repeat length values for words in the list.
- Apply combinations of words onto the partitions. A set of words of equal length will be mapped to length values in a partition. Say for example you have the partition `(15+15+15+10+10+10+10+5+5+5)` then you would generate combinations for all length 15 words over 3, length 10 words over 4, and length 5 words over 3. (I'm ignoring the space separation issue here).
- Generate permutations of all the combinations over all the partitions.

Answer (score 2):

Simplify a bit:  Change all the strings from "xxx" to "xxx ".  Then set the sentence length to 101.  This allows you to use len(x) instead of len(x)+1 and eliminates the edge case for the last word in the sentence.  As you traverse, and build the sentence left to right, you can eliminate words that would overflow the length, based on the sentence you've just constructed.

UPDATE:

Consider this to be a base n number problem where n is the number of words you have.  Create a vector initialized with 0 [NOTE: it's only fixed size to illustrate]:

```
acc = [0, 0, 0, 0]
```

This is your "accumulator".

Now construct your sentence:

```
dict[acc[0]] + dict[acc[1]] + dict[acc[2]] + dict[acc[3]]
```

So, you get `able able able able`

Now increment the most significant "digit" in the acc.  This is denoted by "curpos".  Here curpos is 3.

```
[0, 0, 0, 1]
```

Now you get `able able able baker`

You keep bumping acc[curpos] until you hit `[0, 0, 0, n]`  Now you've got a "carry out".  "Go left" by decrementing curpos to 2.  increment acc[curpos].  If it doesn't "carry out", "go right" by incrementing curpos and set acc[curpos] = 0.  If you had gotten a carry out, you'd do a "go left" by decrementing curpos to 1.

This is a form of backtracking (e.g. the "go left"), but you don't need a tree.  Just this acc vector and a state machine with three states: goleft, goright, test/trunc/output/inc.

After the "go right" curpos will be back to the "most significant" position.  That is, the sentence length constructed from acc[0 to curpos - 1] (the length *without* adding the final word) is less than 100.  If it's too long (e.g. it's already over 100), do a "go left".  If it's too short (e.g. you've got to add another word to get near [enough] to 100), do a "go right"

When you get a carry out and curpos==0, you're done

I recently devised this as a solution to the "vampire number challenge" and the traversal you need is very similar.

Comment: I cannot eliminate the sentence here. I have to truncate extra characters

Comment: What do you mean by 'truncate'? Can you provide an example where truncation occurs?

Comment: @RakeshRanjanSukla So, you mean "able baker charlie" gets trunc'ed to "able baker charl" and that's considered valid?

Comment: Yes, if your sentence is 100 characters you have stop there and truncate the extra characters if you have any.

Comment: But the next sentence creation will start from where you left.

Comment: The 'next' sentence creation? This implies the original list is destructive. Or that something is happening such that after you find one valid sentence the next sentence is working from a different list.

Comment: Yes I am actually encrypting plaintext into ciphertext. Then I will match ciphertext with the one, I have. We have to generate all possible sentences of length 100 here, but there no constraint. The one I can think of is to reduce number of words to 12-15 maybe.

Comment: @RakeshRanjanSukla You might want to reduce it.  You've got 100 words and assuming an average word length of 8 [I took your word list and wrote a program to calc it], number of combinations is 100**8 or 1e16, give or take.  Even with the best alg, this will take a while.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem size is way too large, but if 1) your actual problem is much smaller in scope, and/or 2) you have a lot of time and a very fast computer, you can generate these permutations using a recursive generator.

```
def f(string, list1):
    for word in list1:
        new_string = string + (' ' if string else '') + word
        # If there are other constraints that will allow you to prune branches,
        # you can add those conditions here and break out of the for loop
        if len(new_string) >= 100:
            yield new_string[:100]
        else:
            list2 = list1[:]
            list2.remove(word)
            for item in f(new_string, list2):
                yield item

x = f('', list1)
for sentence in x:
    check(sentence)
```

One caveat is that this may produce identical sentences if two words at the end get truncated to look the same.

Answer (score 1):

I am not going to provide a complete solution, but I'll walk through my thinking.

Constraints:

- A permutation of your complete list that exceeds 100 characters can be immediately thrown out. (Ok, `99 + len(longest_word))`.)
- You are essentially dealing with a subset of the power set of elements in your list.

Given that:

- Build the power set, but discard any sentences that exceed your maximum
- Filter the final set for sentences that exactly match your needs

So you can have the following:

```
def construct_sentences(dictionary: list, length: int) -> list:
    if not dictionary:
        return [(0, [])]
    else:
        word = dictionary[0]
        word_length = len(word) + 1
        subset_length = length - word_length
        sentence_subset = construct_sentences(dictionary[1:], subset_length)
        new_sentences = []
        for sentence_length, sentence in sentence_subset:
            if sentence_length + word_length <= length:
                new_sentences = new_sentences + [(sentence_length + word_length, sentence + [word])]
        return new_sentences + sentence_subset
```

I'm using tuples to write-aside the length of the list and make it easily available for comparison. The result of the above function will give you a list of sentences that are all less than the length (which is key when considering potential permutations: 100 is fairly short so there is a *vast* number of permutations that can be readily discarded). The next step would be to simply `filter` any sentence that isn't long enough (i.e. 100 characters).

Note that at this point you have every possible list filtering your criteria, but that list may be reordered `2^n` ways. Still, that becomes a more manageable situation. With a list of 100 words, averaging under 9 characters a word, you have a average number of words in a sentence equal to 10. `2^10` isn't the worst situation in the world...

You'll have to modify it for your truncation case, of course, but this gets you in the ballpark. Unless I completely missed something, which is *always* possible. I doubly think something is wrong because running this produces a surprisingly short list.